# Use continued fractions to find the fraction k/r that satsfies $\left|\frac{427}{512} - \frac{k}{r}\right| \leq \frac{1}{1024}$

Tags: number-theory, inequality, continued-fractions

Math wizards:

I believe there is only one solution to this for which r>k and that is 5/6. As to the how you get there, I have no idea.

$ \vert {\frac{427}{512} - \frac{k}{r}} \vert \leq \frac{1}{1024}$

(the two vertical lines represent the absolute value)

I can expand 427/512 but don't know how to get to k/r.

$\frac{427}{512} = 0+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{5+\frac{1}{42+\frac{1}{2}}}} $

Where I got this from there is a type of formula: 
[image]

and then: 
[image]

If anyone could explain how you get that formula, and how you go from the continued fraction expansion to $\frac{d_2}{r_2}= \frac{5}{6}$ tha'd be awesome!

:)

Comment: $$(k,r)=(427,512)\ ?$$

Comment: The inequality is equivalent to $$\frac{853}{1024}\leq\frac{k}{r}\leq\frac{855}{1024},$$ which of course implies $r>k$, and there are clearly infinitely many solutions.

Comment: Interpolating what you probably want, $$\frac{853}{1024}=[0; 1, 5, 42, 2]$$ hence $$\frac{216}{259}=[0; 1, 5, 43]$$ is an approximation in the wanted range.

Comment: Probably the Wikipedia essay on continued fractions tells you where all the formulas come from. Or just open a Number Theory textbook. Or consult https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2175005/proof-of-the-formula-for-the-convergents-of-continued-fractions-how-to-start

Comment: Any thoughts on the comments, MAth?

Comment: Earth to MAth, come in, please.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP has abandoned it.