# Find the general term of $a_{2k}=pa_k+qa_{k+1},a_{2k+1}=ra_k+sa_{k+1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, recursion

**The question**

Given that the initial terms $a_1$, $a_2$ and the recursion:

$$
\left\{
\begin{matrix}
a_{2k}=pa_k+qa_{k+1}\\
a_{2k+1}=ra_k+sa_{k+1}\\
\end{matrix}
\right.
$$

Find the general term of $a_n$ in term of $a_1, a_2, p, q, r, s$ and $n$

---

**My work:**

Let
$
A_1=
\begin{pmatrix}
r&s&0\\
0&p&q\\
0&r&s\\
\end{pmatrix}
$,
$
A_0=
\begin{pmatrix}
p&q&0\\
r&s&0\\
0&p&q\\
\end{pmatrix}
$,
$v_1=\begin{pmatrix}
a_1\\
a_2\\
a_3\\
\end{pmatrix}$ and
$v_0=\begin{pmatrix}
a_2\\
a_3\\
a_4\\
\end{pmatrix}$

Then we have:

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
a_{2k}\\
a_{2k+1}\\
a_{2k+2}\\
\end{pmatrix}
=
A_0\begin{pmatrix}
a_{k}\\
a_{k+1}\\
a_{k+2}\\
\end{pmatrix}
,
\begin{pmatrix}
a_{2k+1}\\
a_{2k+2}\\
a_{2k+3}\\
\end{pmatrix}
=
A_1\begin{pmatrix}
a_{k}\\
a_{k+1}\\
a_{k+2}\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

For any integer $n$, $\begin{pmatrix}
a_{n}\\
a_{n+1}\\
a_{n+2}\\
\end{pmatrix}$ can be written as a product of some $A_1$ and $A_0$ actting on $v_1$ or $v_0$. Their order depends on the binary form of $n$

For example:

$6=110_{(2)}$，so

$$\begin{pmatrix}
a_{6}\\
a_{7}\\
a_{8}\\
\end{pmatrix}=A_0A_1v_1$$

$45=101101_{(2)}$，so

$$\begin{pmatrix}
a_{45}\\
a_{46}\\
a_{47}\\
\end{pmatrix}=A_1A_0A_1A_1v_0$$

However, it is difficult to find the closed form of the product as $A_1,A_0$
have different eigenvalues.

**Special Case I:**

When $p=1+\frac{a}{d},q=1-\frac{a}{d},r=\frac{a}{d},s=2-\frac{a}{d}, a_1=a, a_2=a+d$, then:

$$a_n=a+(n-1)d$$

i.e. ${a_n}$ is an arithmetic sequence.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "However, the product is difficult to calculate."? It is just multiplication of $3\times 3$ matrices.

Comment: @Somos Sorry for the confusion. I mean it is difficult to find the closed form of the product. Just like calculating $M^n$, the value can be found easily by diagonalizing the matrix $M$. However, this method does not work as $A_1, A_0$ have different eigenvalues. It is a bit complicated to calculate a long chain of $A_1, A_0$.

Comment: Some similarities with https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2175005/proof-of-the-formula-for-the-convergents-of-continued-fractions-how-to-start

Answer (score 2):

For the longest path, calling $k=2^m$ we have

$$
\left(\matrix{a_{2^{m+1}+1}\\ a_{2^{m+1}}}\right)= M^j\left(\matrix{a_{2^{m-j+1}+1}\\ a_{2^{m-j+1}}}\right)= M^{m+1}\left(\matrix{a_2\\ a_1}\right)
$$

with $M = \left(\matrix{q&p\\ s& r}\right)$. Now if $M = \left(\matrix{1-\lambda&1+\lambda\\ 2-\lambda& \lambda}\right)$ we have

$$
M = T\cdot \Lambda\cdot T^{-1},\ \ T = \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & \frac{\lambda +1}{\lambda -2} \\
 1 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)\ \ \ \Lambda = \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 2 & 0 \\
 0 & -1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

$$
\left(\matrix{a_{2^{m+1}+1}\\ a_{2^{m+1}}}\right)= T\Lambda^{m+1}T^{-1}\left(\matrix{a_2\\ a_1}\right)
$$

so for $\lambda = \frac ad,\ \ a_2=a+d, a_1=a$ and $k = 2^m$ we have

$$
\left(\matrix{a_{2k+1}\\ a_{2k}}\right)= \frac 13\left(
\begin{array}{c}
  \left(2^{m+1}+(-1)^m\right) (a+d)\\
\left(2^{m+1}+(-1)^m\right) (a+d)-3d(-1)^m \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

For $a_1=a_2=a$ with the same $\lambda,k$ we have

$$
\left(\matrix{a_{2k+1}\\ a_{2k}}\right)=\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 2^m \\
 2^m \\
\end{array}
\right)a
$$

Answer (score 2):

The question asks

> Given that the initial terms $a_1$, $a_2$ and the recursion:
> $$
> \left\{
> \begin{matrix}
> a_{2k}=pa_k+qa_{k+1}\\
> a_{2k+1}=ra_k+sa_{k+1}\\
> \end{matrix}
> \right.
> $$
> Find the general term of $a_n$ in term of $a_1, a_2, p, q, r, s$ and $n$

This is essentially a combinatorial problem to determine "generating
sequences" (my ad hoc name) for positive integers.

More precisely, a generating sequence is a sequence of moves beginning
from $1$ or $2$ such that a move from $k$ to $2k$ is indicated by
prepending $p$ to a generating sequence for $k$ or prepending $q$ to
a generating sequence for $k+1$. Similarly, a move from $k$ to $2k+1$
is indicated by prepending $r$ to a generating sequence for $k$ or
prepending $s$ to a generating sequence for $k+1$.

This is a small table of valid generating sequences

$$ \begin{array}{|c|c|} \hline
 n & \text{generating sequences} \\ \hline
 1 & 1 \\ \hline
 2 & 2 \\ \hline
 3 & r1, s2 \\ \hline
 4 & p2, qr1, qs2 \\ \hline
 5 & r2, sr1, ss2 \\ \hline
 6 & pr1, ps2, pq2, qqr1, qqs2 \\ \hline
 7 & rr1, rs2, sp2, sqr1, sqs2 \\ \hline
\end{array} $$

The corresponding table of sequence values is

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|} \hline
 n & a_n \\ \hline
 1 & a_1 \\ \hline
 2 & a_2 \\ \hline
 3 & ra_1 + sa_2 \\ \hline
 4 & pa_2 + qra_1 + qsa_2 \\ \hline
 5 & ra_2 + rsa_1 + ssa_2 \\ \hline
 6 & pra_1 + psa_2 + pqa_2 + qqra_1 + qqsa_2 \\ \hline
 7 & rra_1 + rsa_2 + psa_2 + qrsa_1 + qssa_2 \\ \hline
\end{array} $$

The key phrase is "general term of $a_n$ in term of $a_1,a_2,p,q,r,s$ and $n$"
which seems to indicate a closed form expression. I don't think that
this exists although a proof of this fact would be very difficult.

Notice that for $k>1$ the number of generating sequences for $2k$ and
$2k+1$ are both equal to $A_k$ where $A$ is the
[OEIS sequence A275202](https://oeis.org/A275202). For example,
$A_2=3$ and there are $3$ generating sequence for both $4$ and $5$.

Some special cases of $\,a_n\,$ appear in the OEIS.

A notable example with many references to the literature is the
[Stern-Brocot sequence](https://oeis.org/A002487)

> $\texttt{
> a(0) = 0, a(1) = 1; for n > 0: a(2*n) = a(n), a(2*n+1) = a(n) + a(n+1).}$

Another example is
[OEIS sequence A214126](https://oeis.org/A214126)

> $\texttt{ a(2n)=a(n-1)+a(n) and a(2n+1)=a(n+1) for n>=1, with a(0)=a(1)=1.}$

One more example is
[OEIS sequence A294044](https://oeis.org/A294044)

> $\texttt{a(0) = 0, a(1) = a(2) = 1; a(2*n) = 2*a(n) + a(n+1), a(2*n+1) = a(n) + a(n+1).}$

> $\texttt{G.f. g(x) satisfies g(x) = (x + 2 + 1/x + 1/x^2)*g(x^2) - 1 - 2*x^2. - Robert Israel, Oct 24 2017}$

Comment: For the simpler case: $a_{2k}=pa_k, a_{2k+1}=qa_k$. It is easy to find its closed form  by the help of [$OEIS A000120$](https://oeis.org/A000120). Can we find the closed form of the sequence in the question through $A000120$?

Comment: @eoj As I wrote in my answer, in my opinion, there is no hope of closed form, but I have no proof of that fact. By the way, your question is missing n. That is "Find the general term of $a_n$ in term of $a_1, a_2, p, q, r, s,$ **and** $n$

Answer (score 1):

(Partial answer)

An alternative approach would be the use of the generating function associated to the sequence, as follows :
$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
A(x) 
   &=& \displaystyle
   \sum_{n\ge0} a_nx^n \\
   &=& \displaystyle
   \sum_{k\ge0} a_{2k}x^{2k} + a_{2k+1}x^{2k+1} \\
   &=& \displaystyle
   \sum_{k\ge0} (pa_k + qa_{k+1})x^{2k} + (ra_k + sa_{k+1})x^{2k+1} \\
   &=& \displaystyle
   \sum_{k\ge0} (p+rx)a_kx^{2k} + (q+sx)a_{k+1}x^{2k+1} \\
   &=& \displaystyle
   (p+rx)\sum_{k\ge0}a_kx^{2k} + (q+sx)\sum_{k\ge1}a_kx^{2k-1} \\
   &=& \displaystyle
   (p+rx)A(x^2) + \frac{q+sx}{x}(A(x^2)-a_0)
\end{array}
$$
hence
$$
(q+(p+s)x+rx^2)A(x^2) - xA(x) -a_0(p+rx) = 0
$$
This functional equation can be complicated to solve, but it has the advantage to circumvent the binary considerations.

Comment: Your idea is a good one, but some typos exist. the final equation is $(q/x + s + px + rx^2)A(x^2) - (A(x) + a_1q)x + a_1(1-s)x^2 + (a_2(1-q) - a_1p)x^3 = 0.$

Answer (score 0):

I found 2 ways to calculate $a_{n}$ when $q=0$ i.e.
$$\left\{
    \begin{matrix}
        a_{2k}&=pa_k&\\
        a_{2k+1}&=ra_k&+sa_{k+1}\\
    \end{matrix}
    \right.$$
For convenience, we have the following definetion:
$b_n:=$ number of 1's in binary expansion of n ([OEIS sequence A000120](https://oeis.org/search?q=a000120&language=english&go=Search)).
$l_n:=\lfloor \log_2n\rfloor$ i.e. $l_n$ is one less than the length of the binary form of $n$.
Then, I found that
$$ a_n=s^{l_n}\left(a'_n+\frac{p}{s}(s-1)a'_{n-2^{l_n}}\right)$$
where $a'_n$ is defined as
$$\left\{
    \begin{matrix}
    a'_{2k}&=\frac{p}{s}a'_k&\\
    a'_{2k+1}&=\frac{r}{s}a'_k&+a'_{k+1}\\
    \end{matrix}
    \right.$$
and can be found as follows
$$a'_{n+1}=\sum_{i+2j=n}\left(\frac{p}{s}\right)^{b_i}\left(\frac{r}{s}\right)^{b_j}\left[\binom{i+j}{i}\mod{2}\right]$$
There is an alternative formula
$$a'_{n+1}=\sum_{k=0}^n \lambda^{b_k} \bar{\lambda}^{b_{n-k}}$$
where $\lambda, \bar{\lambda}$ be the roots of       $sx^2-px+r=0$.
Now we know how to find $a'_n$, then we can find $a_n$ through the equation between $a'_n$ and $a_n$. After substitution and simplification, we have
$$a_{n+1}=\sum_{i+2j=n}s^{l_{n}-b_j-b_{2^{l_{n}}+i}+1}p^{b_i}r^{b_j}\left[\binom{i+j}{i}\mod{2}\right]$$
or the alternative form
$$a_{n+1}=s^{l_n+2}\sum_{i+j=n} s^{b_i+b_j-b_{2^{l_n}+i}-b_{2^{l_n}+j}}\lambda^{b_i} \bar{\lambda}^{b_{j}}$$
I will type the proof when I am available.